# Loop when enter is scanf'ed like pacman

Tags: c, while-loop, scanf, archlinux

I'm trying to ask a question in a while with a confirmation in another while which will basically reset the first when the condition is filled.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char Disque[] = "";

    char qDisque[] = "";

    system("clear");

    while (strcmp(qDisque, "y")) 
    {
        system("clear");

        printf("\nLetter for disk : \n");

        scanf("%s", Disque);

        while (strlen(Disque) > 1) 
        {        
            system("clear");

            printf("\nLetter for disk : \n");

            scanf("%s", Disque);
        }

        system("clear");

        printf("Use /dev/sd%s as install disk ? [y|n] : ", Disque);

        scanf("%s", qDisque);
    }
}
```

So far so good. Except that I **CAN'T** imitate the behavior of pacman -S $PKG when it ask to confirm : meanning if I press n it will stop but I can press ENTER type o or whatever it will continue.

My script only accept "whatever keystroke" but enter just add space with scanf() following.

Is there a solution without changing the structure of my code (only change the condition for instance or add functions) ? If not, what should I change in order to make it imitate the pacman behavior ?

The actual behavior of my program is the following (to explain) :

```
Question ? :                      //ENTER keystroke
                                //ENTER keystroke
                                //ENTER keystroke
                                //ENTER keystroke
                                //ENTER keystroke
y                                 //y keystroke
Are you sure ?
                                //ENTER keystroke
                                //ENTER keystroke
                                //ENTER keystroke
n                                 //n keystroke
Okay no changes !
```

Thanks guys (and girls) !

Answer (score 3):

```
char Disque[] = "";
char qDisque[] = "";
```

These both arrays have only one character `'\0'` and nothing else , so there size is `1` . When you take input in them using `scanf` , there is no space for `'\0'` and passing these to string manipulation functions will cause *undefined behaviour*.

You need to *mention their size while declaring* in order to get rid of problem .

### Edit-

Before *initializing* `qDisque` you compare it with `"y"` in `strcmp` -

```
while (strcmp(qDisque, "y"))
```

So, use a `do-while` loop instead of this.

And also this condition if you see `strcmp` return `0` then condition will be false and if it returns `1` then condition will be true .

So condition should be as follow in `do-while` loop -

```
do{
  ...
  //you code
  }while (strcmp(qDisque, "y")==0);
```

So , if `qDisque` is `"y"` then only loop will continue.

Comment: I tried adding 100 but it doesn't affect anything, gcc passed but nothing change, same ENTER behavior (adding annoying spaces).

Comment: @Gradiuss I am sorry I am unable to understand it. Would you mind to give example with input and expected output .

Comment: I managed to add some lines to explain visually what is the exact behavior of my actual program.

Comment: @Gradiuss I have mentioned a edit in answer , Please take a look.

Comment: Changes have been made and still ENTER not behaving at all, only adding more and more spaces instead of doing either a loop or an instruction. I know it just a detail in the process of the code but I found it annoying to know that the user can type ENTER and see space added it's just ugly...

Answer (score 0):

You could use single `char` instead of array's if only one drive letter at a time is needed:

```
char Disque = 0;
char qDisque = 'y';

while(qDisque == 'y')
// ...
```

and use `"%c"` or `" %c"` in `scanf()`. Extra space in case of a previous `\n`.